# How to get a collection that is in a document of another collection in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, api, google-cloud-firestore

So I am creating an API in firebase and in the database there is a collection of universities. Inside this collection there are multiple documents of universities. In each document I've created a collection of users. So inside every university you can see the users that attend this uni. 
What I want to do is everytime I make a request to the server by GET of api/user it shows (through authorization token) my details as a user.

I have created the function that requests the data of a user, by using the Bearer {token} but it seems that, when I console log the university ID is undefined. Inside the user document there is a field called uniId (the id of the university the user belongs and it is the same ID of the university document). I am using postman to make the API requests after I have created the Bearer token with another login function.

```
exports.getAuthenticatedUser = (req, res) => {
  let userData = {};
  db.doc(`/unis/${req.user.uniId}/users/${req.user.handle}`).get()
    .then((doc) => {
      if(doc.exists){
        userData.credentials = doc.data();
        return res.json(userData);
      }
    })
```

I understand that I need to change something in "req.user.uniId" because now that variable is undefined.
Any guidance on how I can approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to add a `userhandle` field to your documents so you can use a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query). Something like this:

```
exports.getAuthenticatedUser = (req, res) => {
  let userData = {};
  db.collectionGroup('users').where('userhandle', '==', req.user.handle)
                             .limit(1)
                             .get()
                             .then(function (querySnapshot) {
                               querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                                 userData.credentials = doc.data();
                                 return res.json(userData);
                               });
                            }).catch(function(error) {
                               console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
                            })
}
```